# Postgresql psql client-server communication

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

Please help: I am looking to improve sequential scan performance on PostgreSQL 9.2 version. As part of my test I am performing "select * from .." query on some big table locally from Unix box, where my DB is running. The table has no indexes and freshly created. It's take 30 sec per 100k rows with output to /dev/null in compare with 7 sec for "create table as select" statement, that not only selects but also writes same data amount. I think the issue is client-server connection. The target is actually JDBC connection that suffers ~same slowness. I am not specified host for psql as it is local connection and for JDBC I am using "localhost".May I do some setting on JDBC or DB level to improve it?

Comment: What's the size of the rows output? try `select sum(length(table.*::text)) from table` for an estimate. if using SSL, turn if off (it's always off for unix domain sockets, but not for TCP localhost)

Comment: is `select * from ...` actually the thing that needs to be improved, or is it just a proxy for something else?  Perhaps you are trying to optimize the wrong thing.

Comment: It's actually that have to be improved. No SSL and even no network: everything is locally. The length is 155 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Network communication will always add some overhead. Also integers, float, numeric, dates, times have to be converted to text and it might have to do character set conversion on text values. The output also needs to be prettily formatted before it is written out. That all takes time. While when creating a new table with the same data many of those conversions never need to happen as everything can stay in it's native binary format. So I do not think there is that much you can do.